# How can I handle login_required in a middle step of a wizard view in other to maintain flow in Django?

Tags: django, formwizard

I have a wizard view that demands for login at the third step. It works, but after login the wizard does not continue to the fourth step but goes back to the first step. This is inconvinient

*views.py

```
FORMS = [("amount", forms.AmountToSendForm),
     ("confirm_amount", forms.ConfirmAmountForm),
     ("receiver", forms.ReceiverForm),
     ("card", forms.CardPaymentForm),
     ("bank", forms.BankPaymentForm),]

...

def login_user(request):
    #login is as imported from django.contrib.auth.views
    return login(request, template_name='roja/login.html',  authentication_form=forms.LoginForm)

class PaymentWizard(SessionWizardView):
    ...
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #initiate attributes of the dispatch method so that the .steps atrribute 
        #of the dispatch method can be exposed
        response = super(PaymentWizard, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs) 

        if self.steps.current == 'receiver':
            @method_decorator(login_required) #as imported
            def inner_dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
                return super(PaymentWizard, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
            return inner_dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs)               
        else:        
            return response
```

*login.html

```
...
<form action="{{ app_path }}" method="post" id="login-form" class="panel-body wrapper-lg">{% csrf_token %}
 ...
```

So:
1. How can I make it continue on to the fourth step?
2. Are there any security considerations I need to be aware of given my implementation?
Thanks Everyone.

Answer (score 2):

So I have cannibalized my code for a while before I found a painfully simple solution. I subclassed the NamedUrlSessionWizardView following the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views.NamedUrlSessionWizardView).

i.e. instead of

```
class PaymentWizard(SessionWizardView):
    ...
```

I have:

```
# If you have different templates for each step add this
# and use as below 
TEMPLATES = {                                                               
"amount": "pay/amount.html",                                            
"confirm_amount": "pay/amount_calculated.html",                         
"receiver": "pay/receiver.html",                                        
"card": "pay/card_form.html",                                           
"bank": "pay/bank_success.html",                                        
}         

class PaymentWizard(NamedUrlSessionWizardView):
    ...
    def get_template_names(self):
        return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]
```

Then in *urls.py*

```
from pay.views import PaymentWizard, FORMS

payment_wizard = PaymentWizard.as_view(FORMS, url_name='pay_step', done_step_name='finished')


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...,
    url(r'^(?P<step>.+)/$', payment_wizard, name='pay_step'),
)
```

Since the individual steps have urls that django recognized it was trivial to redirect to the referring url after login.

*Still need to know if there are security concerns to be wary of.*